# Separating videos from photos in Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, video

I've got about 700 videos in lightroom, and I want them to be separate so I can work on them with a totally separate workflow. I was thinking about removing all the videos from my photo folders and just dealing with them in premiere but when I took the video I also took photos and so the videos are kind of 'in context' in the photo library. Any suggestions about workflow for dealing with this situation? Is there a reason why videos are able to be imported into Lightroom, when my perception of it is that it is photography software?

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, but I think you've answered exactly the part about why they're able to be imported when you say _"he videos are kind of 'in context' in the photo library"_. It sounds like you don't want to lose that — is the question really how to _keep_ that but keep it useful in your workflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to filter down to your video files in Lightroom, create a [smart collection](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/photo-collections.html#work_with_smart_collections) and specify the collection is for files with **Media Type** = **Video**. [Or in Lightroom Classic: **File Type** = **Video**].

Lightroom 4 added some basic video processing features, so [Lightroom can process video files](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/video-lightroom.html), not just still images.

Comment: **2022 Update:** In Lightroom Classic, it's File Type = Video.

Comment: @cb4. Thanks edited it in.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a solution for moving videos to another folder.

I used [`exiftool`](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). It's free and cross-platform (including Linux). However it's command line and can take some mental work to figure out.

Something like this below would import video files (based on the file extension) from F:\MyMess and move them into a directory structure à la Lightroom (YYYY\MM\DD), under F:\MyVideos

```
cd F:\MyVideos
exiftool.exe -CreateDate -DateTimeOriginal -r -m -d %Y/%m/%d "-Directory<DateTimeOriginal" "-Directory<CreateDate"  -ext MP4 -ext AVI -ext MOV -ext MPEG "F:\MyMess"
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/rolfen/244c691660839c27941cd371683039ba#organizing-photos-by-date) (and more tricks).

Answer (score 1):

### **2022 Lightroom Classic**

1. Create a smart collection of all your video files with File Type = Video.
2. Right-click the smart collection and export it as a catalog to another folder (or drive) with enough space.
3. LrC copies all of the video files to the destination *in the exact same folder hierarchy* as they exist in your current catalog.
4. Use the new catalog when you want to work on your videos.

One (good) caveat: My catalog was not 100% in sync with the file system. This being the first time I tried this procedure, I wanted to make sure it was accurate. Checked the file system against my catalog and found different counts. Turns out I had duplicate videos in the file system!